# Balance between number of Threads and machine spec (CPU and RAM) for LP

Tags: multithreading, linear-programming, specifications

I'm facing problems with the balance of performance and machine specification for LP optimization. I'm currently using an m5.12xlarge (48vCPU, 192RAM) but frequently I find the machine workload in high processing and low memory usage. Right now I am using only 35/98 threads. What do you guys recommend to get a better performance? Should I increase threads? Can I change the machine to c5.12xlarge (48vCPU, 96 RAM) to decrease memory? Could you please recommend some references about it?

Comment: This is way too broad. LPs are hard to parallelize and most solvers won't attempt this (in a real parallel way), but just start *concurrent portfolios* (primal simplex vs. dual simplex vs. sifting, vs. interior-point). There are some exceptions, e.g. research-code. So for LPs, the number of cores is not the most important factor. *The solver used is!* There is also the question if the cloud is the right platform as thread-migration can kill a lot of performance and the BLAS/LAPACK-code used internally will struggle with this. More memory only helps when needed to start more concurrent solvers.

Comment: Of course above only applies to pure LPs and if you are solving MIPs (tree-search), things change a lot. But well. you wrote LP. And before saying: "indeed i'm solving MIPs, what then?": specifics matter and general recommendations are hard without (except: yes, parallelization is easier there, but there is not much in regards to guaranteed speedups).